# Dropdown combination in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I am trying to make this drop-down combination work for a project but apparently this is not working. Can you please check the error in this code.

This is the html code.

```
<select id="chartSelect" onchange="changeChart(this.value);">
   <option value="Line">Line Chart</option>
   <option value="Pie">Pie Chart</option>
   <option value="Map">Choropleth Map</option>
</select>
<select id="dataSelect" onchange="changeData(this.value);">
   <option value="House">House Data</option>
   <option value="Toilet">Toilet Data</option>
</select>
```

and this is the javascript portion;

```
function changeChart(ele){
   var value = chartSelect.options[chartSelect.selectedIndex].value;
   if (value==="Pie"){
      var dataType = dataSelect.options[dataSelect.selectedIndex].value;
      if (dataType === "House"){
         alert("This is pie chart(HOUSE)");
      }
      if (dataType === "Toilet"){
         alert("This is pie Chart(TOILET)");
      }
   }
   if(value=="Line"){
      var dataType = dataSelect.options[dataSelect.selectedIndex].value;
      if(dataType == "House"){
         alert("This is line chart(HOUSE)");
      }
      if (dataType == "Toilet"){
         alert("This is line chart(TOILET)");
      }
   }
};
```

This is the link to jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rFXTk/

Comment: Why can't you use Firebug or Google Chromes Developers console to help you debug?

Comment: My console, specifically tells me `Uncaught ReferenceError: ele is not defined `

Comment: i tried. i really could not do this.

Comment: When I change a value, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: changeChart is not defined `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one more error in changedata() function is not defined, and one more thing changeChart(this.value); but there is no use of this.value in side the function, so i have refined your code to error free.[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rFXTk/2/)

```
function changeChart() {
            var value = chartSelect.options[chartSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            if (value == "Pie") {
                var dataType = dataSelect.options[dataSelect.selectedIndex].value;
                if (dataType == "House") {
                    alert("aakarshan")
                }
                if (dataType == "Toilet") {
                    alert("DHAKAL")
                }

            }

            if (value == "Line") {
                var dataType = dataSelect.options[dataSelect.selectedIndex].value;
                if (dataType == "House") {
                    alert("BIVAV")
                }
                if (dataType == "Toilet") {
                    alert("SATYAL")
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem. In your jsfiddle, your function is being loaded in an onload (because it is set to do so in the JSFiddle options). If it is in an onload, is only available to the onload function and not the HTML itself.

My Update: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/rFXTk/1/

I just changed: `onload` to `No wrap - in <head>`. I also removed that function which had the undefined variable `ele` in it even though that had nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written here is correct, but your fiddle js section has a additional line. Just remove it from the fiddle and it will work.

The only thing is that you dont have definition for the ChangeData(), please add it.
You need to add all the conditions. It is working with the written conditions.